# PL/SQL no data found exception handling

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table EMAILS with columns: ROUTINE, EMAILS and COPIES defining to whom the result of particular procedure should be sent (as to/cc) using UTL_MAIL.

I have the following code:

```
PROCEDURE myproc AS
  NO_EMAIL_FOUND EXCEPTION;
  e EMAILS%ROWTYPE;
  x NUMBER;
BEGIN

  --fetch data
  SELECT x INTO x FROM <...>;

  --fetch emails
  SELECT * INTO e FROM emails WHERE routine='FRS_WEEKLY';
  IF e.emails IS NULL AND e.copies IS NULL THEN
    RAISE NO_EMAIL_FOUND;
  END IF;

  <send mail code using UTL_MAIL>;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_EMAIL_FOUND THEN <code1>;
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN <code2>;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; --RAISE;

END myproc;
```

I want myproc to execute *code1* when there's no emails in EMAILS table. My problem is that NO_EMAIL_FOUND exception is not raised and *code2* executed since NO_DATA_FOUND exception is raised before it in SELECT statement. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
PROCEDURE myproc AS
    NO_EMAIL_FOUND EXCEPTION;
    e EMAILS%ROWTYPE;
    x NUMBER;
BEGIN

    BEGIN
        --fetch data
        SELECT x INTO x FROM <...>;

        --fetch emails
        BEGIN
            SELECT * INTO e FROM emails WHERE routine='FRS_WEEKLY';
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RAISE NO_EMAIL_FOUND;
        END;
        IF e.emails IS NULL AND e.copies IS NULL THEN
            RAISE NO_EMAIL_FOUND;
        END IF;

        <send mail code using UTL_MAIL>;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_EMAIL_FOUND THEN <code1>;
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN <code2>;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; --RAISE;
    END;

END myproc;
```

Comment: Yap, the solution is to enclose my SELECT into internal BEGIN EXCEPTION END structure, internally catch NO_DATA_FOUND, and and propagate it up as wanted NO_EMAIL_FOUND, finally catch it. IF e.emails IS NULL ... then is not needed any more. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
PROCEDURE myproc AS
  NO_EMAIL_FOUND EXCEPTION;
  e EMAILS%ROWTYPE;
  x NUMBER;
BEGIN

  --fetch data
  SELECT x INTO x FROM <...>;

  --fetch emails
  BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO e FROM emails WHERE routine='FRS_WEEKLY';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE NO_EMAIL_FOUND;
  END;

  IF e.emails IS NULL AND e.copies IS NULL THEN
    RAISE NO_EMAIL_FOUND;
  END IF;

  <send mail code using UTL_MAIL>;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_EMAIL_FOUND THEN <code1>;
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN <code2>;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; --RAISE;

END myproc;
```

I hope you are aware that this routine can only process exactly one email; if there is more than one, a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception will be raised.

Comment: Column 'routine' is PK in my EMAILS table so there will be no TOO_MANY_ROWS (one record per proc execution and one mail). Of course, one email but with more email addresses.